# A problem concerning catalan number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Show that the number of ways to stack coins with n coins in the bottom row is denoted by Catalan number $$D_n = \frac{(_{2n}C_n)}{n+1}$$. I have tried in the way described in the picture below[image]

Comment: A is the centre of first coin and B is the centre of 3rd coin( the last one). I established a bijection between the number of ways of stacking the coin AND the number of ways of travelling from A to B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a row of $n+1$ coins below the bottom row of $n$ coins. Call the centre of the leftmost new coin $P$ and the centre of the rightmost new coin $Q$. The centres of all of the coins form a triangular lattice. We look at certain lattice paths from $P$ to $Q$. Specifically, we allow only moves one step up and to the right or one step down and to the right. Moreover, if it is possible to move up and to the right, we require that this move be made. It’s not hard to see that each stack of coins with an original bottom row of $n$ coins corresponds under these rules to a unique lattice path from $P$ to $Q$.

Each of these paths is essentially a [Dyck path](http://www.findstat.org/DyckPaths) from $P$ to $Q$. Since each step takes it one unit to the right, it must have exactly $2n$ steps. It’s not hard to check that each Dyck path from $P$ to $Q$ corresponds to a stack of coins with an $n$-coin original base. Finally, it’s [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) that there are $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ Dyck paths of length $2n$. Thus, $D_n=C_n$.

**Example:** The Dyck path shown below, with $n=4$, corresponds to the stack shown to its right:

```
         *   *                    O O  
        / \ / \                  O O O O
       *   *   *   *  
      /         \ / \  
     *   *   *   *   *  
     P               Q
```

Comment: @Brain Scott: I  know only 3 kinds of dyck paths. This seems to be a different dyck path. What is the property of this kind of dyck path?

Comment: I think it can be better called as mountain ranges. But what is the property?

Comment: @VamsiSpidy: It starts and ends on the $x$-axis and never goes below the $x$-axis. If you think of each up-step as a left parenthesis and each down-step as a right parenthesis, these paths correspond to valid parenthesis strings.

Comment: @VamsiSpidy: You’re welcome.

Comment: @M.Scott: i didnt really understand your solution. Could you please explain show the dyck paths that correspond that to the stack with 3 coins at the bottom

Comment: Scott: " Specifically, we allow only moves one step up and to the right or one step down and to the right. Moreover, if it is possible to move up and to the right, we require that this move be made. "  Could you please explain elaborately the above 2 sentences